# linking to self created dll fails

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, clion, mingw-w64

using CLION i did create a very basic "C++ Library" containing only one function. Library Type is "shared". 
in Library.h there is only a

```
void hello();
```

function declaration. 
Library.cpp contains the definition

```
void hello(){std::cout << "hello";}
```

When i compile it, i get 2 files: libLibrary.dll and libLibrary.dll.a.

Here comes my problem. When i create a new Project named Test (an executable), i can include the Library.h file with no problems. But it wont compile due to an "undefined reference to `hello()'" which is no surprise, because i did not link to the created DLL-File. I added "target_link_libraries" to the CMakeLists.txt and copied both DLL-Files to the same directory where the executable is to be build.

The CMakeLists file looks as follow:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(Test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test Library)
```

its always the same error-message:

```
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686/w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLibrary
```

I did also try

```
target_link_libraries(Test libLibrary)
target_link_libraries(Test -libLibrary)
target_link_libraries(Test -Library)
target_link_libraries(Test libLibrary.dll)
target_link_libraries(Test Library.dll)
target_link_libraries(Test -libLibrary.dll)
```

...to no avail.

What did i miss?

Comment: I think you  don't have your library in a folder that your linker is looking

Comment: You need to have a CMake command that defines Library as a target like: `add_library(Library ...)` then you can use `target_link_libraries(Test Library ...)` see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html

Comment: @drescherjm: Thanks for your hint: "target_link_libraries(Test ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libLibrary.dll)" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

i could finally link against the .dll-File by specifying the concrete location of the .dll-file, as @drescherjm suggested. Here linking to the .dll-File was successful with the command

```
target_link_libraries(Test ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libLibrary.dll)
```